# "Invalid Object Format Name" in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

When working with Crystal Report Field Objects and attempting to set "EnableSuppress" to False  or alter the position or width of a field object is generating an "Invalid Object Format Name" error.  The debugger shows all my code running without error until attempting to actually load the report.  At that point, it will run the first couple without problem, then it fails when messing with a field object, and none of the rest will run. The code is shown below.  Everything that generates an error is a FieldObject, but not all fieldObjects generate errors.  In the code below, everything in Section2 is a TextObject and everything in Section3 is a FieldObject.

```
If condition = True Then
'Lines marked as runs ok, only run when a line that generates an error is not present before it.  
    Report.Section2.ReportObjects("Text7").Left = 7830      'Runs ok  
    Report.Section3.ReportObjects("Field4").Left = 8085     'Runs ok  
    Report.Section2.ReportObjects("Text13").ObjectFormat.EnableSuppress = False    'Runs ok  
    Report.Section3.ReportObjects("Field28").ObjectFormat.EnableSuppress = False   'error  
    Report.Section2.ReportObjects("Text9").Left = 10830     'Runs ok  
    Report.Section3.ReportObjects("Field23").Left = 10830   'error  
    Report.Section3.ReportObjects("Field23").Width = 615    'error  
    Report.Section2.ReportObjects("Text10").Left = 11445    'Runs ok  
    Report.Section3.ReportObjects("Field25").Left = 11445   'Runs ok  
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried to suppress the fields in the Crystal Report using a formula?

Comment: I could suppress in the Crystal Report, but that doesn't help me move and change the width of Field23 (in the code I posted).

Comment: Have you tried a different value for Field23? Test to see if it is a conflict with the value (maybe use the same value as Field25) or the field itself.

Comment: That seems to be working.  Field25 is a number (Int) and Field23 is just text (pulled out of a database).  Would that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't. Does Field25 come from the database? What about the other fields that throw errors?

Comment: I misspoke earlier (maybe).  All of the fields used (including 23 and 25) come from a database, but it is passed into VB as a dataset, which is then passed to crystal.  We have done this elsewhere in our code and it is working.

Comment: And you know that you can change size and position of fields within Crystal by right-clicking on the field and clicking "Size and Position"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you figure out what is different about the fields that throw errors and are absolutely set on formatting in VB code, I suggest that you do your formatting from within the Crystal report. You obviously know about the conditional suppression and to change size and location of a field you can right-clicking on the field and clicking "Size and Position". There is also an option for conditional placement (formula).

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Using formulas seems to fix this problem.  It doesn't work with field objects for whatever reason.  I am just going to wrap everything up in formula fields.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that works for you. Sometimes Crystal doesn't play well with others and you're better off staying within Crystal. Cheers!